# Shared Volume Docker Permissions

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to create an abundance of Docker containers. All of the containers have a shared volume.

```
volumes:
  - ${PHP_SERVICES_FOLDER}:/var/www/web
```

The docker containers are as follows.

- Jenkins(FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest) - This writes to the shared volume
- Nginx(FROM nginx) - This reads from the shared volume and uses the php-fpm container
- PHP-FPM(FROM php:7.2-fpm)

With the volume's files having permissions 777 Nginx and PHP can read, write and execute the files but as soon as I trigger a build in Jenkins which updates files in the volume.

I think the reason it works when the permissions are 777 is because that allows 'other' users full access to the volume.

How can I have Nginx, PHP-FPM and Jenkins use the same user to read, write and execute files in that volume?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an user in each of the Dockerfiles using the same `uid` and then give permissions to user with those `uid`s.

For example:

```
# your dockerfile
RUN groupadd -g 799 appgroup
RUN useradd -u 799 -g appgroup shareduser
USER shareduser
```

Then you simply need to `chown` everything in the volume with the newly created `uid` (in any container or at host, as `uid`s are shared between container and host:

```
chown -R 799:799 /volume/root/
```

Comment: Just a small question... RUN useradd -r -u 799 -g appgroup shareduser. The addgroup is meant to be a new group correct? And is that meant to be on the host and the container?

Comment: I added the group with specific gid to the dockerfile. The idea is that all containers will have rights to it. On the host system both owner and group will be displayed as simply `799` (or other `uid`:`gid` of your choosing). Nothing prevents you from creating the same users with same `uid`s in the host if you need that as well. The permissions are completely tied to the `uid:gid`s

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. So I slightly went a different route but followed the same concept as your answer. If you want to update your answer to make it more relevant to my question feel free to and ill mark it as the correct answer.

Basically, in the Nginx and PHP-FM containers, I update the www-data user id to 799 instead of changing the users that these containers run on, I do the same for the jenkins container. This way, all the default users run using the same user id.